# "Socket id" is null while a connection is established in Flutter

Tags: flutter, socket.io

I use the following code to establish a connection with socket.io:

```
  late IO.Socket _socket;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _socket = IO.io('http://192.168.1.3:3001',
        IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket']).build());

    print(_socket.id);
  }
```

When I run the app, `_socket.id` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to connect the socket like below

```
_socket.connect();
```

But the Way you're writing your code is not good.
You can follow below pattern.

```
IO.Socket socket;
@override
void initState() {
  initSocket();
  super.initState();
}
initSocket() {
  socket = IO.io('http://192.168.1.3:3001', IO.OptionBuilder().setTransports(['websocket'])
.disableAutoConnect() .build());
      socket.connect();
      socket.onConnect((_) {
        print('Connection established');
      });
      socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('Connection Disconnection'));
      socket.onConnectError((err) => print(err));
      socket.onError((err) => print(err));
    }
```

Comment: When I Connect for the first time, `_socket.id` is null but when I reconnect it get id. Why?

Comment: try to print id inside the onConnect(). Because onConnect() will by default called when the socket is connected. And if you're directly printing .id after the socket.connect() then sometimes the socket will take some time to connect and that's why it will not print id.